# SQL Server Merge Two Tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two slightly different tables:

Table 1:

```
    Sm Reads Oct
Install, Date, Con, MT
```

Table 2:

```
Sm Reads
Contract, Inst, Read T, Date
```

New Table:

```
Sm Reads Master
Contract, Install, Date, Type
```

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE [Sm Reads Master]
(
    [Contract] FLOAT,
    [Install] FLOAT,
    [Date] DateTime,
    [Type] NVARCHAR (3)
)
GO

INSERT INTO [Sm Reads Master]
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT * FROM [Sm Reads Oct]
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM [Sm Reads]
        ) LU
```

I suppose it doesn't like the fact that the two tables have different field names and different data, so is it even possible to do this?

Thanks for any help.

(MT in the first table is the same data as Read T in the second)

Comment: I think, you just need to re-order the column sequence as per your new table.

Comment: Specify your column in the `select` statement

Comment: your union query is not correct .Column Name must be same and also in same sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your union query is not correct .Column Name must be same and also in same sequence*

*Try following script :*

```
INSERT INTO [Sm Reads Master] ([Contract],[Install],[Date],[Type])
SELECT [Contract] = Con,
                [Install]  = Inst, 
                [Date],
                [Type]     = MT
        FROM [Sm Reads Oct]

        UNION

        SELECT  [Contract],
                [Install], 
                [Date],
                [Type]
        FROM [Sm Reads]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the same column-names (and types):

```
INSERT INTO [Sm Reads Master]
SELECT * FROM   
FROM    (
        SELECT  Contract = Con,
                Install  = Inst, 
                Date,
                Type     = MT
        FROM [Sm Reads Oct]

        UNION

        SELECT  Contract,
                Install, 
                Date,
                Type
        FROM [Sm Reads]
        ) LU
```